# Python merge all child list into parent list and remove duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a huge list of lists.
I want to Merge all child lists to parent list
and remove duplicates item from parent list after merge.

**What is the optimized way to do this?**

For Example:

```
x = [['a', 'b', 'c', 2, 4], ['x', 1, 2, 3, 'z'], ['z', 'b', 'y', 'a' 'x']]
```

How we can get the value of x like:

['a', 'b', 'c', 1, 2, 3, 4, 'z', 'y', 'x']

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: Why is the number `4` missing?

Comment: The output does not make sense to me. You sure about it? The order is strange and values are missing.

Answer (score 4):

Use set and chain:

```
x = [['a', 'b', 'c', 2, 4], ['x', 1, 2, 3, 'z'], ['z', 'b', 'y', 'a' 'x']]

from itertools import chain

result = list(set(chain.from_iterable(x)))
print(result)
```

Comment: This changes the sequence of elements in the result list.

Comment: Is there a difference between `chain.from_iterable(x)` or `chain(*x)`, and what is it?

Answer (score 4):

Use `set`

```
x = [['a', 'b', 'c', 2, 4], ['x', 1, 2, 3, 'z'], ['z', 'b', 'y', 'a' 'x']]
>>> list(set([item for sublist in x for item in sublist]))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'z', 'ax', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y']
```

Answer (score 2):

first you can convert the `list` of `list` into a one `list` and than apply `set` to that `list`.

```
x = [['a', 'b', 'c', 2, 4], ['x', 1, 2, 3, 'z'], ['z', 'b', 'y', 'a' 'x']]
new_ls=[]
for ls in x:
    new_ls.extend(ls)
print(list(set(new_ls))
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'ax', 'b', 'y', 'x', 'c', 'z', 'a']
```